# display unique row from two tables

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables (one for quarter one, one for quarter two), each of which contains employees who have bonus in that quarter. Every employee has a unique id in the company.

I want to get all employees who has bonus in either q1 or q2. **No duplicate employee** is needed. Both **Id, and Amount** are required.

Below is my solution, I want to find out if there is a better solution.

```
declare @q1 table (
EmployeeID int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
amount int
)


declare @q2 table (
EmployeeID int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
amount int
)


insert into @q1 
(amount)
select 1

insert into @q1 
(amount)
select 2

select * from @q1

insert into @q2
(amount)
select 1

insert into @q2 
(amount)
select 11

insert into @q2
(amount)
select 22

select * from @q2
```

My Solution:

```
;with both as
(
select EmployeeID
from @q1
union
select EmployeeID
from @q2
)
select a.EmployeeID, a.amount
from @q1 as a
where a.EmployeeID in (select EmployeeID from both)
union all
select b.EmployeeID, b.amount
from @q2 as b
where b.EmployeeID in (select EmployeeID from both) and b.EmployeeID NOT in (select EmployeeID from @q1)
Result:

EmployeeID, Amount

1   1
2   2
3   22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, SUM(amount) AS TotalBonus
FROM
(SELECT EmployeeID, Name, amount
from @q1
UNION ALL
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, amount
from @q2) AS all 
GROUP BY EmployeeID, Name
```

The subselect UNIONS both tables together. The GROUP BY gives you one row per employee and the SUM means that if someone got lucky in both qs then you get the total. I'm guessing that's the right thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT q1.EmployeeID --- Same as q2.EmployeeID thanks to the join
        , q1.EmployeeName -- Not defined in OP source.
FROM    @q1 AS q1
        CROSS JOIN @q2 AS q2
WHERE   q1.amount IS NOT NULL
        OR q2.amount IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Both Id and name are required

Comment: So, select it too. Answer modified.

Comment: Thanks. But it returns 2 rows. It should return 3 rows.

Comment: The inner join means that an employee had to be in the q1 table to show up in the join - I think Pingpong wanted a UNION. A CROSS JOIN might have done it.

Comment: My mistake. I read "in either q1 or q2" as "in both q1 and q2". Modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
SELECT EmployeeID
FROM EmployeeList
WHERE EmployeeID IN
    (SELECT EmployeeID From QuarterOne  
        UNION
     SELECT EmployeeID From QuarterTwo)
```

OR by using `JOIN`

```
SELECT EmployeeID
FROM EmployeeList a INNER JOIN QuarterTwo b 
           ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
     INNER JOIN QuarterTwo c 
           ON a.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID
```

This will return all `EmployeeID` that has record in either quarter.

Comment: @Pingpong `EmployeeList` is the name of the table. You can change that to the name of your table which contains all employees.

Comment: There is no such a table in the question

Comment: @Pingpong you can change `EmployeeList`, `QuarterOne`, and `QuarterTwo` to the name of your tables.